# FPGA access on a MacBook-Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hardware-acceleration

I am interested in accelerating machine learning on a MacBookPro using FPGA technology. Has anyone found a way to attach an FPGA card or dev board to Thunderbolt interface?

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt can transport PCIe x4, and there are plenty of Thunderbolt PCIe expansion boxes out there. They're roughly the size of an external desktop hard drive enclosure, and provide a PCIe x4 slot that hooks up to Thunderbolt.

So buy a PCIe FPGA card that requires x4 or less, and put it in one of these boxes.